# Почему не получается передать структуру в метод другого класса?

Tags: c#

Я создаю структуру. Потом ее создания я заполняю и хочу каждый элемент этой структуры передать в другой метод и там уже (в другой БД) выполнить вставку данных. Вот код:

```
    void selectDataForSync() //data from PG that whould be insert in SQLLITE
    {
        UserData ud;
        List<UserData> uds = new List<UserData>();

        NpgsqlConnection conn =
             new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=" + config.PGLogin + ";" +
                                  "Password=" + config.PGPass + ";");            

        conn.Open();

        string SQLrequest = @"SELECT guid, username, ""FL"", id, userblob FROM ""USERS"" WHERE ""FL""=10;";
        NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(SQLrequest, conn);

        try
        {

            NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader(); // here exception
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                // UserData ud = new UserData();
                ud.id = Int32.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
                ud.guid = (dr[1].ToString());
                ud.name = (dr[2].ToString());
                ud.userblob = (byte[])dr[3];
              //  uds.Add(ud);

                sqllite.insertDataFromPGToSQLLite(ud);
            }
            dr.Dispose(); // releases conenction

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
```

Упорно [ругается](http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/04/25/571e23db6216d.png) на строку:
`sqllite.insertDataFromPGToSQLLite(ud);`
Мол: `argument type is not assignable to parameter type`

Определение самой структуры выглядит [так](http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/04/25/571e23374b358.png)

На SQLLite стороне код такой:

```
  public struct UserData
   {
       public int id;
       public string guid;
       public string name;
       public byte[] userblob;
   };


  public void insertDataFromPGToSQLLite(UserData ud)
    {

    }
```

Comment: написано же: разные типы. Используйте `DBSync.DB.SQLLite.UserData ud;`

Comment: Почему разные то?
`UserData ud; ` объявил тип
`sqllite.insertDataFromPGToSQLLite(ud);`
передал данные
Я структуру в часть SQLLite добавил такую же как тут. Посмотрите пост, я его обновил.

Comment: Тип `UserData` определен в двух местах: `DBSync.Postgres` и `DBSync.DB.SQLLite`.  Вы объявили переменную типа `DBSync.Postgres.UserData`, а методу `sqllite.insertDataFromPGToSQLLite` нужна `DBSync.DB.SQLLite.UserData`.

Comment: Не могли бы показать как мне объявить надо? У этих данных же структура одинаковая.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тип `UserData` определен в двух местах: `DBSync.Postgres` и `DBSync.DB.SQLLite`.  Вы объявили переменную типа `DBSync.Postgres.UserData`, а методу `sqllite.insertDataFromPGToSQLLite` нужна `DBSync.DB.SQLLite.UserData`.

Оставьте только одно определение типа `UserData` и везде его используйте.

> У этих данных же структура одинаковая.

Это не имеет значения. Для компилятора это два совершенно разных типа.

Comment: Так, а объявление `UserData` получается объявить в отдельном классе и везде импорт сделать? Ну чтобы он и там и там был виден.

Comment: В отдельном файле или даже в отдельном проекте (Class Library), но на данном этапе это, возможно, перебор.

Comment: так? http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/04/25/571e2a574d37c.png
И дальше `using UserDataStruct`?

Comment: да, если этот тип находится в `namespace UserDataStruct`